how to deal with csv special characters
I have a problem in my bash script, that converts json file to csv file (with some specific requirements), it was working well, but today I discovered a bug, here is a line for example:
"tst1,tst2","tst3","\"tst4\" tst5,tst6","tst7"
then i upload it on google sheets
and it supposed to be like:
cell1: tst1,tst2
cell2: tst3
cell3: \"tst4\" tst5,tst6
cell4: tst7
but it looks like:
cell1: tst1,tst2
cell2: tst3
cell3: \tst4\" tst5
cell4: tst6"
cell5: tst7
I tried a solution to but it is not perfect, I tried to escape " using "" instead of \".
I need to know all special characters in csv and how to escape them
